# Python - Scraping web data - using Ecommercetools module

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm new to python, I'm still familiar with Scraping web data function. Here's my code

```
from ecommercetools import seo

mysearch=input('What do you need to search?')
results = seo.get_serps(mysearch,pages=2,domain=google.com)
```

My question: regarding the last function seo.get_serps, it has the option to change the domain, since its default is google.co.uk, I want to change it to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com). How can you specify it in the "results" line though? Thank you

results = seo.get_serps(mysearch,pages=2)
While I try running this, as compare to google results, there are 1 or 2 results not matched completely. Therefore I was wondering how to change the domain to make it proper. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, upgrade to the latest version of EcommerceTools by entering `pip3 install --upgrade ecommercetools`

... then, try this. You'll need to set the `domain` to your preferred one and set the `host_language`. The domain needs to be a valid Google domain and the `host_language` needs to be a valid two-letter language code, i.e. `de` or `en`.

```
from ecommercetools import seo

df = seo.get_serps("bmw", pages=1, domain="google.de", host_language="de")
df
```

Comment: Hi, I did upgrade it as you mentioned. I use the function below, but it shows error as : 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'

|results = seo.get_serps(mysearch,pages=2,domain="google.de", host_language="de")|